# Show listview custom section index while scrolling listview

Tags: android, listview, fastscroll, sectionindexer

I am implementing an Android listview with fastscroll and SectionIndexer.
Similar to the address book - you know when you scroll it fast it will indicate where you are in the alphabetical list by an arrow with a letter on.
In my case the list is not simply sectioned alphabetically and I need to show a slightly longer text than just a single letter. My problem is that the text is wider than the arrow. So how can I change the look of the indicator shown while scrolling? (Changing the style of the arrow and eventually make the text smaller.)